# How to make subplots in donut pie chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

How can Python's matplotlib be used to make subplots for donut pie charts?

Below is the code I wrote :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue']
explode = (0, 0, 0)  # explode a slice if required
subgroup_names = ['A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'C.1']
subgroup_size = [13, 3, 5, 6, 5, 10]
a, b, c = [plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens]

plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, pctdistance=0.45, labeldistance=0.65, colors=colors, autopct='%.2f%%', shadow=True)
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.175, color='black', fc='white', linewidth=1.25)

plt.pie(subgroup_size, labels=subgroup_names, pctdistance=0.85, labeldistance=1.25, colors=[a(0.5), a(0.4), a(0.3), b(0.5), b(0.4), c(0.6)], autopct='%.2f%%', shadow=True)
centre_circle2 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.275, color='red', fc='white', linewidth=1.25)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle2)


plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The result shows like below picture :

[image: this is result image from my coding]

But I hope the result will look similar to the below image :

(I have to display the percentage value)

[image: this is the result I hope come out(with percentage value)]

Comment: There is an example for nested charts in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-nested-pie-py). Can you apply it here and then ask for the remaining problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib documentation has very nice examples for almost everything you can dream of. Please see [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-nested-pie-py) for a nested pie chart.

Following the comment on link-only answers, the keyword radius is what you are looking for in your call to pie(). It takes in a float which determines the absolute radius of your pie. Drawing nested pies thereby requires multiple calls to pie(), each with a different value of radius. Please see an example below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pie([1, 2, 3], radius=1,
        colors=['xkcd:cerulean', 'xkcd:bright red', 'xkcd:grass green'],
        labels=['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C'], autopct='%.2f%%',
        pctdistance=0.85, shadow=True,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='white'))

plt.pie([0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 1.5, 0.1, 3], radius=0.7,
        colors=['xkcd:sky blue', 'xkcd:light blue', 'xkcd:reddish pink',
                'xkcd:salmon pink', 'xkcd:baby pink', 'xkcd:apple green'],
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='white'),
        labels=['A.1', 'A.2', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'B.3', 'C.1'], autopct='%.2f%%',
        pctdistance=0.8, labeldistance=0.4, shadow=True)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

which returns the following plot
[image]