# Center and arrange nested pie charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I try to produce a nested pie chart with two rings representing three classes (inner chart) and more classes in outer pie chart. Outer chart should represent categories within inner chart. It should look something like one example [link to the image](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fprolaborate.sparxsystems.com%2Fimg%2FPortalPage%2FCharts%2Fnestedpie-chart-relationship.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fprolaborate.sparxsystems.com%2Fresources%2Fdocumentation%2Fenterprise-architecture-charts-and-visualizations%2Fnested-pie-chart&tbnid=_BXYXp260flpCM&vet=12ahUKEwjusrms0Lf2AhWmgv0HHcxzBXAQMygEegUIARDDAQ..i&docid=5I-ExC71522o0M&w=605&h=582&q=nested%20pie%20chart%20with%20grouping%20matplotlib&ved=2ahUKEwjusrms0Lf2AhWmgv0HHcxzBXAQMygEegUIARDDAQ#imgrc=_BXYXp260flpCM&imgdii=K3gXTcWA_WgF3M) below. Any help would be very helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/Course_Data/main/test_pie_chart.csv")
# Set the figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
# Count each cateries
outerData={}
for i in data.Col1:
    if i not in outerData:
        outerData[i]=1
    else:
        outerData[i]+=1
innerData={}
for i in data.Col2:
    if i not in innerData:
        innerData[i]=1
    else:
        innerData[i]+=1

outerLabels = list(innerData.keys())
outerSizes = list(innerData.values())

innerLabels = list(outerData.keys())
innerSizes = list(outerData.values())
outerColors = ['#FFCE53', '#FFDA7E', '#FFE9B2', '#30B7EA','#56C7F2','#7FD6F7', '#B3E7FB']
innerColors = ["#DFFF00","#FFBF00","#FF7F50"]
 
bigger = plt.pie(outerSizes, labels=outerLabels, colors=outerColors,
                 startangle=90, frame=True)
smaller = plt.pie(innerSizes, labels=innerLabels,
                  colors=innerColors, radius=0.7,
                  startangle=90, labeldistance=0.7)
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.4, color='white', linewidth=0)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
        
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [concentric pie charts on discourse.matplotlib.org](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/how-to-draw-concentric-donuts-chart/18617); [radial labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239733/matplotlib-move-labels-into-middle-of-pie-chart): [How to make subplots in donut pie chart using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293382/how-to-make-subplots-in-donut-pie-chart-using-matplotlib)